# How to remove # from url in angular?

Tags: angular, routes

Hash(#) coming along with the url .

I tried removing the {usehash:true} and also changed the  LocationStrategy, after that # will get removed but lot of issues wil come . it will show 404 if we refresh the page. Is there any way to sort this out

Comment: Where is the hash coming from, i.e. how do you get the url? Is it a string from some service, some api response? Care to share some code, example or errors you get?

Comment: coming along with the route localhost:5008/#/dashboard like this

code 
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],

Comment: Please share some code, especially part where you import RouterModule with `useHash: true`, and specify if you're using HashLocationStrategy or PathLocationStrategy and, in fact, specify why you do/don't need the hash in the first place.

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
  // { path: '', redirectTo: 'p', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'p', loadChildren: () => import('../app/core/core.module').then(x => x.CoreModule) },
  { path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: () => import('../app/apps/apps.module').then(x => x.AppsModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'p', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.